# Why does value of a variable not change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

((Sorry for my bad English))
I created a public static bool variable in one of the scripts and named it `inDamage`. And then I use it, depending on the value. In an another script I use RayCast, and if the ray hits a collider, `inDamage = true`, else - false. This script (with RayCast) is on several objects, maybe this is the problem. But if I deleted all copies of this script except one, it wouldn't work. So why does value of the variable not change?

There is the script:

```
Ray2D ray2D = new Ray2D(transform.position, transform.right); 
RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(ray2D.origin, ray2D.direction, 10); 
if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Player")) 
{     
    ScriptName.inDamage = true; 
} 
else 
{     
    ScriptName.inDamage = false; 
}
```

I tried to make this variable not static and change the value in the script where it was declared, it worked. But I need to get information from the RayCast.

Full script:

```
public class Light : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int DefaultLenght = 10; // Length of ray if it doesn't hit anything
    public int MaxReflectionCount = 5; // Max count of ray reflections

    private List<Vector3> _hitPoints = new List<Vector3>();
    private LineRenderer _lineRenderer;

    void Awake()
    {
        _lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastWithReflection();
    }

    private void RaycastWithReflection()
    {
        _hitPoints.Clear(); // Clearing array of points to move line in a new frame
        _hitPoints.Add(transform.position); // Adding starting point into the array

        Ray2D ray2D = new Ray2D(transform.position, transform.right);

        while (_hitPoints.Count <= MaxReflectionCount) // Line will reflect till it reaches the max count of ray reflections
        {
            RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(ray2D.origin, ray2D.direction, 10); // Variable with an information about raycast


            if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Mirror")) // Ray will reflect if it hits the mirror
            {
                _hitPoints.Add(hitInfo.point);
                ray2D.origin = hitInfo.point - ray2D.direction * 0.01f;
                ray2D.direction = Vector2.Reflect(ray2D.direction, hitInfo.normal);
            }
            else if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Untagged")) // Ray ends if it collides with a regular wall
            {
                _hitPoints.Add(hitInfo.point);
            }
            else // If ray is not colliding with anything its length equals DefaultLength
            {
                _hitPoints.Add(ray2D.origin + ray2D.direction * DefaultLenght);
            }
            
         Vampire.inDamage = hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Player");
        }

        _lineRenderer.positionCount = _hitPoints.Count;
        _lineRenderer.SetPositions(_hitPoints.ToArray()); // Finally, rendering the ray itself
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ScriptName?

Comment: could just be `ScriptName.inDamage = hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Player");` for the 6 lines of the conditional

Comment: @shingo it is the first script, where I declared variable inDamage

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss ok, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Do all these RayCast scripts share the same ScriptName? And how does this piece of script run, FixedUpdate or an event?

Comment: No it does not solve the problem which is why it is just a comment but I don't think we have enough code in the example provided to really fix this here.

Comment: @shingo FixedUpdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what you re trying to achieve is hitting the player with some reflections in the mirrors etc

So actually as soon as you hit the player I guess you simply want to not further process any rays and just do e.g.

```
private void RaycastWithReflection()
{
    _hitPoints.Clear(); // Clearing array of points to move line in a new frame
    _hitPoints.Add(transform.position); // Adding starting point into the array

    Ray2D ray2D = new Ray2D(transform.position, transform.right);

    // Line will reflect till it reaches the max count of ray reflections
    // OR hits the player
    while (_hitPoints.Count <= MaxReflectionCount) 
    {
        var hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(ray2D.origin, ray2D.direction, 10); 

        // If ray is not hitting anything its length equals DefaultLength and ENDS
        if(hitInfo.collider == null)
        {
            _hitPoints.Add(ray2D.origin + ray2D.direction * DefaultLenght);
            // leave the while loop -> no further raycasts!
            break;
        }

        // Ray will reflect if it hits the mirror
        if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Mirror")) 
        {
            _hitPoints.Add(hitInfo.point);
            ray2D.origin = hitInfo.point - ray2D.direction * 0.01f;
            ray2D.direction = Vector2.Reflect(ray2D.direction, hitInfo.normal);
        }
        // Ray ENDS if it hits the player and sets Vampire.inDamage
        else if(hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Vampire.inDamage = true;
            // leave the while loop -> no further raycasts!
            break;
        }
        // Ray ENDS if it collides with anything else
        else
        {
            _hitPoints.Add(hitInfo.point);
            // leave the while loop -> no further raycasts!
            break;
        }
    }

    // Finally, rendering the ray itself
    _lineRenderer.positionCount = _hitPoints.Count;
    _lineRenderer.SetPositions(_hitPoints.ToArray()); 
}
```

then whoever is actually handling the `Vampire.inDamage` would also be responsible to reset it afterwards, this way it should not be a problem with potentially having multiple instances of this script

Comment: Wow, it works! But only if I change `if (hitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Mirror"))` to `if (hitInfo.collider != null)` . And also `else` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the static bool is set by several raycasts in the while loop. And most of them set the value to false. So when a ray hits and inDamage is set to true, it is immediately overwritten by the next raycast to false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to delete all copies of RayCast and it didn't work

Comment: @Jrtq why accepting this answer as the solution then? :D